# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable 3

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv

csvfile = open(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\canberra_2011_2012.csv")

header = csvfile.readline()  
csv_f = csv.reader(csvfile)   
for row in csv_f:
    first_value = float(row[5]) 
    total = sum(first_value)
    length = len(first_value)
    average = total/length
    print("average = ",average)
```

When i run this code, it said

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

But when I change the line 7 to

```
first_value = [float(row[5]) for row in csv_f
```

then it works. This confuses me, can anyone help me?

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: What do you want `sum(first_value)` to produce? As it is, you're trying to sum the single value found in the 6th column of each row by itself. The indented code runs separately once for each row in your spreadsheet.

Comment: This is python, so how can i fix it?

Comment: Your list comprehension already did fix it, didn't it? Your `sum` and `len` both assume that `first_value` is a list of values, not a single value. Making it actually a list of values (probably with a better name) fixes it.

Comment: if I use first_value = [float(row[5]) for row in csv_f], it did fix it. but to find the average is just task one, in task two, it asked me to find the average value in both year 2011 and year 2012. the third column of this file is the year, so I plan to test when value in column 3 equals 2011, then output the value in column 6, but the output is "[]" without any value

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is much more elegant than mine, but the following is closer to the spirit of your original code.  It may make your errors more obvious.  I apologize for the crappy formatting.  I'm new to this site.

```
import csv
csvfile = open(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\canberra_2011_2012.csv")

header = csvfile.readline()  
csv_f = csv.reader(csvfile)
length = 0
total = 0.0   
for row in csv_f:
    first_value = float(row[5])
    total = total + first_value
    length += 1
if length > 0:
    average = total/length
    print("average = ",average)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to collect all the `first_value`s and then do some calculations. To do that, you must step through each row of the csv file and first collect all the values, otherwise you are summing one value and that's the source of your error.

Try this version:

```
import csv


with open(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\canberra_2011_2012.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    values = [float(line[5]) for line in reader]

# Now you can do your calculations:

total = sum(values)
length = len(values)
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error at this line of your code,

```
total = sum(first_value)
```

The error is raised because `sum` is a `function` of `iterable` object. As in your code, the `first_value` is a `float` object. So you can not use `sum` function on it. But when you use list compression,

```
first_value = [float(row[5]) for row in csv_f]
```

then the `first_value` is a `list` type object consisting the `float` values of `row[5]`. So you can apply `sum` function on it without raising error.

Apart from list compression, you can also append the values in a list in your `for` loop and calculate the `sum` and `length` after the loop.

```
first_values = []
for row in csv_f:
    first_value = float(row[5])
    first_values.append(first_value)

total = sum(first_values)
length = len(first_values)
average = total/length
```